# RESTful link_to :method => destroy in Rails 3, with fallback for users with javascript disabled

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rest, ujs

Is there a simple RESTful way to have a fallback url for the `link_to` with `:method => :delete` that will work for folks who have javascript disabled?

For example, suppose I have a list of comments.  To add a link to delete a comment, I might put:

```
<%= link_to "Delete", comment_path(comment.id), :method => :delete %>
```

This would produce a link with the `data-method="delete"` that my ujs driver (jquery_ujs in my case) will turn into a DELETE request.  However, when javascript is turned off, the link is followed as a GET request (as advertised in the docs), and my controller gets rightfully confused.

Is there a good and simple way to resolve this problem?  There's [Railscast 77](http://railscasts.com/episodes/77-destroy-without-javascript), which shows one solution, but this seems to require an awful lot of extra code and throws out the quite elegant `:method => :delete` solution.  I'd be OK with it producing a link to a confirm-delete page when javascript is disabled.

The only solution I can think of is to use `button_to` on the page and UJS to replace it with the corresponding `link_to`.  This somehow doesn't seem quite right to me, but maybe it's OK?  Any other ideas?

Comment: If anyone is interested, I wrote some jQuery to replace a button_to with an almost-equivalent link_to.  I don't think I'll end up using that method here because the button_to doesn't give me a chance to get confirmation unless I introduce an extra controller method (like delete in the link posted by Max), but I could see it working in other situations.

Answer (score 1):

Personally i don't like the idea of mapping the `:delete` to a `:get`, it's not RESTFul...The solution i use is the same than the one you have been thinking about, ie a `button_to` instead of the `link_to`, and if needed i can use CSS to style the button so that it looks like a link.

Comment: I don't see any problem with mapping a `delete` action to a `get` so long as he's not modifying any records in the action.  If he continues to use the `destroy` action which requires a `post` with `_method = delete`, it's still RESTful.  

`button_to` is an option, but make sure you don't use it within another form.  

The `get` delete / `post` delete method is how ASP.NET MVC does it, with the `get` redirecting to a confirmation form and the `post` actually deleting the record.

Comment: Thanks both.  I think I agree that it's still RESTful as long as the destroy action is what actually does the destroying.  It still seems  inelegant, though.